# Getting an ADObject on different server

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I am trying to use powershell to automate some tasks I want to do. We built an AD tool, but its simply good for looking up.

The AD object is in another domain, and its telling me:

```
 Get-ADObject : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.
```

The server runs ADWS just fine, as im using LDAP and another tool to browse it.

It does take different credentials on that server, and im passing them in.

This is what my code looks like. With the redactions.

```
     $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "Oher Domain Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Other Domain Username", $secpasswd)


Get-ADObject -Filter "" -Server "My other domain Server" -Credential $mycreds
```

any help would be great

Comment: Are you using 'username@OtherDomain.tld' or 'OtherDomain\username' as username? If not, there is a problem.

Are your domains are in one forest and trust each other? Are you running script from domain machine? Are you using server's FQDN name? Is TCP port 9389 on remote server is available for you?

Comment: more info than i know. i am using username@otherdomain as my usename

Comment: 1) Try `TELNET DomainControllerServerName.OtherDomainName.tld  9389` from your PC   2) `username@otherdomain` - you should know FQDN name of `otherdomain`, it's more likely you forgot tld ( `username@example.com` if remote domain's DNS name is example.com; or `EXAMPLE\username` if remote domain's netbios name is EXAMPLE ). Each domain have two names - DNS name and Netbios name.

Comment: ive been using LDAP to do these searches and when loging in , I have not had to add the tld.